# Can we get how many times an owner signed the transaction?

Tags: safe-core, safe-core-sdk

Is it possible to get how many times an owner signed the transaction? Currently, I'm using the Safe Transaction Service API and maybe it has an endpoint for that? or is there any other way to do it, maybe with safe SDK or else?

Comment: Do you mean how many times an owner signed transactions (plural) in your safe? If not, what transaction are you talking about? Owners should be able to sign a specific transaction only once. Thanks in advance for clarifying 

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.